# Kubuntu Reverse Scrolling does not work

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, kde

I'm using KDE PLasma 5.5.5 in Kubuntu 16.04 on ASUS X556UF laptop. Sadly even enabling reverse mouse scrolling in the system settings does not work for me. I've had a look at other options for similar questions in the forum. Either they don't work at all or they are not compatible with KDE.

Can anyone help me debug what is going wrong?

PS. Reverse scrolling does not working, but 2 finger scrolling in the other direction does work

Comment: I think the issues with KDE/Kubuntu reverse scrolling have been there long term. I for one still see them on bluethooth mice where there settings are completely ignored on connect, and then one needs to disable and re-enable for it to work